# The getter 'docs' was called on null as QuerySnapshot is null even after it's initialised in initState()

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Here's my code which results in the error:
It's also worth noting that print('mysnapshot.docs.length') prints the length fine indicating that mysnapshot is not null
after initState. However, in the widget builder block, mysnapshot's value is null for reasons I can't figure out.

I am new to Flutter and I'd appreciate a dumbed-down answer. This is also my first question on Stackoverflow. Thanks in advance.

```
class _PlayQuizState extends State<PlayQuiz> {
  DatabaseService serv = new DatabaseService();
  QuerySnapshot mysnapshot;


  @override
  void initState() {

    serv.getQuestionData(widget.quizID).then((value){mysnapshot=value; print(mysnapshot.docs.length);});
  

    print("${widget.quizID}");
    super.initState();
  }
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(title: Row(
      children: [
        SizedBox(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/5.8,),
        appbar(context),
      ],
    ),backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,elevation: 0.0,iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black54),),body:
   

          Text(mysnapshot.docs.length.toString()), // Mysnapshot is null, can't figure out why
      ],),),);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*InitState* and *build* method are fired up very close to each other, so it's normal that a new variable declared in *initState* won't appear in your build method. What you can do instead is making use of `FutureBuilder` widget where it's `future` argument will be the exact same declaration as the one inside *initState*;

```
FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              future: serv.getQuestionData(widget.quizID),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                }
                return Text(snapshot.data);
              },
            ),
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, that seemed to do the trick. Upvoted :)